# What can be done to increase a 72dpi quality icon for high quality impression?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a 300dpi file for high quality impression and I want to use a web icon (from a free license icon deposit) with 72dpi. It looks blurry when printed. Is there something I could do to make it looks better?

Comment: It looks blurry because your software scales it up using its default algorithms. On the other hand, if you scale it up *manually*, you can use "nearest neighbor ", which - yes! - will result in a sharp high resolution image.  (It goes without saying this will not magically add pixels that weren't there to begin with.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quality of the final output depends completely on the amount of original pixels. You may be able to make it look a tiny bit better, but as Rad said, there's no way to add pixels that weren't there in the original.

An icon image 200x200 pixels can look okay on a monitor at 72 dpi, but printing requires minimum 150 to 300 dpi, or higher. So a small image will be blurry, or pixelated when printed, unless you print it really tiny.

If you need to print it larger, you can try bringing the icon into Illustrator and convert to a vector image using **image trace**, or just recreate it. Then it will print higher quality, because now it's a vector.

Comment: I found a 300dpi SVG icon and I tried to use it but the blurry was still there. I simply saved the SVG file and dragged it into Photoshop. Did I something wrong? Or there is something I could do better to ensure a better quality? Because in theory I should be able to resize a 300dpi SVG file without quality loss, right?

Comment: No, the image quality totally depends on the amount of pixels.  DPI is not a measurement of pixels. It just defines how small or large the image will be displayed. The more pixels, the larger the image will print or display. To see what I mean, google some images, hover over them to see the pixel counts, and see how the various sizes display on the screen.